# Dynamically Retrive Row Index in foreachloop

Tags: c#, datatable

how to retrive row index dynamically in FOREACH LOOP

```
foreach(datarow row in datattable)
{
    if(objdt.row[0]["name"].equal("1"))
}
```

But here i want dynamic index for each row of data table 
like i want `objdt.row[dunamic index]["cell"]`

Comment: Why not use a `for loop` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an integer before the foreach:

```
int rowIndex = 0;

foreach(datarow row in datattable)
{
    if(objdt.row[rowIndex]["name"].equal("1"))
    rowIndex += 1;
}
```